# CloudFormation error: "only 1 subschema matches out of 2"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

I want to update the stack, get this error message:

> Properties validation failed for resource RDSDBinstance with message:
> #: #: only 1 subschema matches out of 2 #/DBSubnetGroupName: failed validation constraint for keyword [pattern]

I'm very confused with `#: #` part of the message, google shows there's usually a kind of path pointing to the place with error. No errors in CloudTrail. More confusing, I have 5 environments already which already got this update successfully.

The new code:

```
  subnetDatabase0:   # similar for the second subnet, just 
                     # another AZ and third octet of the CidrBlock
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: !Sub "${Cidr}.14.0/24"
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ "0", !GetAZs "" ]

  RDSSubnetGroup:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup
    Properties:
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Sub "${ProjName}-db-subnetgroup"
      DBSubnetGroupDescription: !Sub "${ProjName} DB subnet group"
      SubnetIds:
        - !Ref subnetDatabase0
        - !Ref subnetDatabase1

  sgDBInternalAccess:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: !Sub "${ProjName}-db-internal"
      GroupDescription: Enable internal access to DB
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 5432
        ToPort: 5432
        CidrIp: !Sub "${Cidr}.4.0/24"

  RDSDBinstance:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    DependsOn:
      - DbUser
      - DbPwd
    Properties:
      DBInstanceIdentifier: !Ref SanitizedDomain
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref RDSSubnetGroup
      DBName: classerium_backend
      DBInstanceClass: !Ref PgInstType
      AllocatedStorage: "20"
      Engine: postgres
      EngineVersion: !Ref PgVersion
      MasterUsername: !GetAtt DbUser.response
      MasterUserPassword: !GetAtt DbPwd.passw
      StorageType: gp2
      BackupRetentionPeriod: 30
      CopyTagsToSnapshot: True
      DeleteAutomatedBackups: False
      VPCSecurityGroups:
        - !Ref sgDBInternalAccess
```

The only difference with the old code is this part was added

```
  StorageType: gp2
  BackupRetentionPeriod: 30
  CopyTagsToSnapshot: True
  DeleteAutomatedBackups: False
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly are `subnetDatabase0` and `subnetDatabase1`?

Comment: @Marcin added to the code

Comment: It seems to fail due to allowed naming pattern for DBSubnetGroupName, what value did you pass for "ProjName" as it gets substituted here "${ProjName}-db-subnetgroup"

Comment: `projName` might be too long: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-resource-providers-rds/blob/315c093c743aa12cf0c438c5ab480a71058b6ab5/aws-rds-dbsubnetgroup/aws-rds-dbsubnetgroup.json#L11

Comment: `ProjName` is just domain name, 24 symbols long. It is the same as in the present state, and the subnet group with that name already exists. Please note it's not a stack creation but update, and resource `RDSSubnetGroup` remains unchanged during this update.

Comment: **Perhaps something was wrong on the AWS side: I've restarted the same update few minutes ago and it passed successfully.**

Answer (score 4):

Because the error message seems a bit obscure, it is the second part of the error message that give you a hint about what went wrong.

I got a similar error message for the creation of a RDS instance:

> `Properties validation failed for resource RDSDemoInstance486243A2 with message: #: #: only 1 subschema matches out of 2 #/MasterUsername: failed validation constraint for keyword [pattern]`

The solution was the */MasterUsername* hint. I used characters for the database username that were not allowed by AWS.
In your case it could have been a problem with **illegal characters** in your **DBSubnetGroupName**